# Get universities names from OpenStreetMap

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, maps, openstreetmap

I'm trying to get universities names, from an **OpenStreetMap** embedded to this website https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/.

I have tried to automate this task using Python Selenium Library, and I hover over all universities one by one and take their names, it seemed fine but when I took a deep look, I found some wrong data, I think that happened when the script tried to hover over a spot which was full of universities, which made it hover over a different university and take its name, I thought about **zooming** than taking the name than zooming out, but this will take really too long and may cause some run time errors by missing a zoom in or a zoom out.

I don't have a considerable knowledge in maps, so I want to ask if there is any way to take the names of the marked universities on the map at once.

If anyone needs the code I tried, it was this one:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep

# setup drivers
PATH = "/Applications/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/")

# find all class elements =leaflet-interactive
nodes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("leaflet-interactive")

# use actionchains
nodelist = []

# loop through each node
for node in nodes:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(node).perform() # Used actionchains class to click to open popup
    sleep(.5)
    nodelist.append(BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml').find(class_=lambda value: value and 'leaflet-tooltip leaflet-zoom-animated' in value).text.lower())
```

which was inspired from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810615/seleneium-exceptions-arguments0-click-is-not-a-function-using-execute-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This service uses http streaming. It will just open an http connection on the following endpoint:

```
POST https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/__sockjs__/n={random_token}/t={token}/w={workerID}/s=0/{random_num}/{random_token2}/xhr_streaming
```

And it will send commands using the following endpoint :

```
POST https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/__sockjs__/n={random_token}/t={token}/w={workerID}/s=0/{random_num}/{random_token2}/xhr_send
```

You can check the result looking for `xhr_streaming` in the network tab in Chrome development console.

The `token` is retrieved from another http call on :

```
GET https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/{workerIDFull}__token__
```

while the `workerID` is present in the original page itself

Some parameters named singletons are necessary and are also located in the original page in a `script` tag like this :

```
<script type="application/shiny-singletons">fafb5589cb5a9f24485f3df0511b50d5cd0c7497,603e796bcfc2ab3685167d58c426f64c15a95192</script>
```

The following script :

- scrape the required elements from the original page
- get the token using workerID
- launch the POST /xhr_streaming in a new thread
- send the "open channel command" on POST /xhr_send which is `'["0#0|o|"]'`
- send the "init command" using the singletons values previously scraped and a large JSON static config

The complete code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
from random import choice
from string import ascii_letters,digits
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import json

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get("https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

singletons = soup.find("script", {"type":"application/shiny-singletons"}).text

workerIDFull = soup.find("base")["href"]
workerID = re.search('_w_(\w+)', workerIDFull).group(1)
timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

r = session.get(f"https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/{workerIDFull}__token__",
    params = {
        "_": timestamp
})
token = r.text

random_token = ''.join(choice(ascii_letters) for i in range(18))
random_token2 = ''.join(choice(ascii_letters) for i in range(8))
random_num = ''.join(choice(digits) for i in range(3))

def getData():
    r = requests.Request("POST", f"https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/__sockjs__/n={random_token}/t={token}/w={workerID}/s=0/{random_num}/{random_token2}/xhr_streaming").prepare()
    resp = session.send(r, stream=True)

    for line in resp.iter_lines():
        if line:
            print(line)
            splitted = str(line.decode('unicode_escape'))[2:-2].split("|")
            if (len(splitted) > 2):
                data = json.loads(splitted[2])
                if ("values" in data):
                    print([ t["args"][8] for t in data["values"]["homeMap"]["x"]["calls"] if t["method"] == "addCircles"][0])

def openChannel():
    r = session.post(f"https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/__sockjs__/n={random_token}/t={token}/w={workerID}/s=0/{random_num}/{random_token2}/xhr_send",
    data = '["0#0|o|"]', headers = {"Content-Type":"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"})

def sendInit():
    data = json.dumps({
        "method":"init",
        "data":{
            "sidebarItemExpanded":None,
            "sidebarCollapsed":True,
            "resetAll:shiny.action":0,
            "fallResetAll:shiny.action":0,
            "lawResetAll:shiny.action":0,
            ".clientdata_output_authModal_hidden":False,
            ".clientdata_output_homefullOnlineVB_hidden":False,
            ".clientdata_output_homepOnlineVB_hidden":False,
            ".clientdata_output_homeHybridVB_hidden":False,
            ".clientdata_output_homepPersonVB_hidden":False,
            ".clientdata_output_homePersonVB_hidden":False,
            ".clientdata_output_homeTBDVB_hidden":False,
            ".clientdata_output_homeOtherVB_hidden":False,
            ".clientdata_output_homeTotalShownVB_hidden":False,
            ".clientdata_output_homeMap_hidden":False,
            ".clientdata_output_graphStateFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallBarGraph_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_covidAthleticGraph_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_schoolCovidPlot_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_intlFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_intlGraph_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_facultyBarGraph_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_stateTrendsGraph_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_covidHeatmap_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_announceHeatmap_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_onlineHeatmap_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_springBreak_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_peerInstPicker_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_statusFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_rankcatFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_hospitalFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_covidFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_campusTypeFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_sectorFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_ccbasicFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_divisionFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_conferenceFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_sizeSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_resHallSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_sportsRevenueSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_intlSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_onlineVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_announcedVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_noDecisionVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_totalVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_dateSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_springMap_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallPeerInstPicker_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallStatusFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallRankcatFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallFacultyFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallHospitalFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallCovidFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallCampusTypeFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallSectorFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallCcbasicFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallStaffFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallDivisionFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallConferenceFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallSizeSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallResHallSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallSportsRevenueSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallIntlSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallfullOnlineVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallpOnlineVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallHybridVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallpPersonVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallPersonVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallTBDVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallOtherVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallTotalShownVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_fallMap_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_greFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_modelFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_planFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_videoPlatformFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawSectorFilter_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawMinoritySlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawLSATtwofiveSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawLSATmedianSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawLSATsevenfiveSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawAcceptanceSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawFYSlider_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawFullOnlineVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawPartialOnlineVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawHybridVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawPersonVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawNDVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawTotalVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_lawMap_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_intlOnlineVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_intlHybridVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_intlInPersonVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_intlCovidVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_intlTBDVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_intlTotalVB_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_output_intlMap_hidden":True,
            ".clientdata_pixelratio":1,
            ".clientdata_url_protocol":"https:",
            ".clientdata_url_hostname":"collegecrisis.shinyapps.io",
            ".clientdata_url_port":"",
            ".clientdata_url_pathname":"/dashboard/",
            ".clientdata_url_search":"",
            ".clientdata_url_hash_initial":"",
            ".clientdata_url_hash":"",
            ".clientdata_singletons": singletons,
            ".clientdata_allowDataUriScheme":True
        }
    })
    r = session.post(f"https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/__sockjs__/n={random_token}/t={token}/w={workerID}/s=0/{random_num}/{random_token2}/xhr_send",
    data = f'["1#0|m|{json.dumps(data)[1:-1]}"]', headers = {"Content-Type":"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"})

thread = Thread(target = getData, args = ())
thread.start()
sleep(1)
openChannel()
sendInit()
thread.join()
```

Checkout the field `data["values"]["homeMap"]["x"]["calls"]` if you need more data from the map

[run this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/universityApi)

Answer (score 0):

This code works, but even optimized it'll take **A LOT** of time to take univeristy names by opening and closing popups.
Bertrand solution should be better than using Selenium in this context!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        
        
        
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--window-size=600,600");
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        
        
        driver.get("https://collegecrisis.shinyapps.io/dashboard/");
        
        WebElement tmp = null;
        
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        
        ArrayList<WebElement> paths = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        
        ArrayList<WebElement> markers = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        
        while(markers.size() <= 0) {
            
            paths = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.className("leaflet-interactive"));
        
            
        for(int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
            
            System.out.println(i);
            
            if(paths.get(i).getAttribute("stroke-linecap") != null)
        if(paths.get(i).getAttribute("stroke-linecap").contains("round"))
            {markers.add(paths.get(i)); System.out.println(markers.get(0));}
        
        }
        
        
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++) {
            
            if(i == 0) {
                
                for(int j = 0; j < markers.size(); j++) {
                    
                    js.executeScript(
                            "arguments[0].style.pointerEvents = 'none';", 
                            markers.get(j));
                }
                
                
            }
            
            js.executeScript(
                    "arguments[0].style.pointerEvents = 'auto';", 
                    markers.get(i));
            
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", markers.get(i)); 
            
            try {markers.get(i).click();}
            catch(Exception e) {js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", markers.get(i));}
            
             System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.className("leaflet-popup-content")).findElement(By.xpath("b[1]")).getText());
             
             ArrayList<WebElement> popupPane = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
             
             for(int k = 0; k < popupPane.size(); k++) {
                 
                 try {
                 if(popupPane.get(k).getAttribute("class").contains("leaflet-pane") && popupPane.get(k).getAttribute("class").contains("leaflet-popup-pane"))
                     {tmp = popupPane.get(k); break;} }
                 
                 catch(Exception e){}
                 
             }
            
             ArrayList<WebElement> children = (ArrayList<WebElement>) tmp.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
             
             while(children.size() > 0) {
             
                 children = (ArrayList<WebElement>) tmp.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
                 
             try {
            driver.findElement(By.className("leaflet-popup-close-button")).click(); }
             catch(Exception e){}
             
             }
            
            js.executeScript(
                    "arguments[0].style.pointerEvents = 'none'", 
                    markers.get(i));
            
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++) {
            
            System.out.println(markers.get(i).getText());
            
            
        }
        
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(markers.size()));
        
        }
```